# converting pacific time string to time

Tags: php

I have time strings like PT19H15M, PT10H, PT5M etc.

PT19H15M is equals 19:15
PT10H is equals 10:00
PT5M is equals 00:05

I want convert each string to usual time.

is there any built-in method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are formatted as [ISO 8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), which is supported by [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), which has the handy method [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

So for example:

```
echo (new DateInterval("PT19H15M"))->format("%H:%I");
```

will output:

```
19:15
```

---

Note that the "PT" in them does not stand for Pacific Time. The P stands for period and indicates the start of the duration representation, while the T indicates the beginning of the time portion - years, months, and such are supported too, e.g. P2YT19H would be 2 years 19 hours.